# How to invert sorting of comments in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, comments

I would like to know how to be able to invert the sorting order of comments in Wordpress.
Normally, the oldest comment is shown first, and then the more recent ones are displayed.

Comment: Try Dashboard/Settings/Discussion and change the option under Other comment settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to **Settings -> Discussion**. Navigate to **'Other comment settings'**

Change the **'Comments should be displayed with the'** to **'newer'**

**Save** settings